# Internet Explorer Swipe Stealing Scroll

Tags: wordpress, scroll, swipe, touchscreen

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Metaslider. This plugin allows users to swipe on a touch screen to view different slides. For some reason, on a touch screen, when using Internet Explorer, the swiping hijacks the scroll event so that when you are trying to scroll down the page and touching the metaslider, the page doesn't scroll. This is a problem because the metaslider is rather big, and to not be able to scroll down the page. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post the solution to this question. I had found it a while back. In case someone else runs into the same problem here is the solution:

```
.flexslider {
    touch-action: pan-y !important;
}
```

That allows you to scroll on top of the metaslider in Internet Explorer on touch screens.